# How to make UIView subclass's frame immutable ouside

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I want to write an UIView's subclass whose frame is immutable outside(e.g. UIPickerView,UISwitch).So I try to override layoutSubviews,sizeToFit and setFrame,but not working.
Who knows how to implement it like UIKit's UIPickerView or UISwitch,thanks.

Update:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame        
{
    [super setFrame:frame];
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
}
```

I cannot set the view's frame using _frame,so when I write these,I will enter a endless loop.

Comment: Post the code when you override setFrame:

Comment: Your code will cause a stack overflow. How meta.

Answer (score 2):

Override [`-setBounds:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW1) to constrain your view to a given bounds.

Something like this should work:

```
static CGFloat maxHeight = ...;
static CGFloat maxWidth  = ...;

- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
   CGSize size = bounds.size; 
   size.width = MIN(maxWidth, size.width);
   size.height = MIN(maxHeight, size.height);

   bounds.size = size;
   [super setBounds:bounds];
}
```

Comment: @DJean: Our way of saying thanks is through upvotes and acceptance of answers — click the hollow checkmark at the left to accept an answer. Please also do this for your previous questions, otherwise you may get nagged at again later. See also: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

`self.frame = newFrame` is essentially the same as calling `[self setFrame:newFrame]`, that's why it enters an endless loop.

However you can just do it like that:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame        
{
    [super setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
}
```

Note that this sets the anchor point (top left corner) to (0,0) which might not be what you intend. Use `setBounds:` instead or pass the origin along to super:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame        
{
    [super setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, 200, 200)];
}
```